# call to write() fails unknown reason

Tags: c, file-io

I open a file with open(), I checked my file descriptor and seems to be ok (3).
But when I try to write on this fd, write() returns -1.
I also print my string, which is shown correctly.

```
errno = 9, "Bad file descriptor"
```

Comment: code might be helpful.

Comment: did you open it with the "write" option? Does your file have write permisions?

Answer (score 0):

```
I checked my file descriptor and seems to be ok (3)
```

Your file descriptor is apparently not open for writing. From the documentation for `write`:

> EBADF
>   fd is not a valid file descriptor or is not open for writing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the functions given in the standard library stdio.h. Use fopen() to open the file, fprintf() to write to a file, and fclose() to close the file. Example:

```
FILE *fh;

fh = fopen("test.txt","w");

fprintf(fh, "Hello World!\n");

fclose(fh);
```

I would bookmark this site as it's an invaluable resource for standard C programming (hint: please check there first ;)
http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/